# How does kafka decide which consumer reads a message within a single consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm wondering if there's any logic which determines which consumer reads a message within the same consumer group. I have a single topic, and a single consumer group. However, I have one or more consumers because there's a consumer deployed in production environment and when I run my application locally another consumer is created which subscribes to the same topic (it's a test project so it's not real production and I'm not worried about loss of data). I noticed that interestingly always the local consumer consumes any given message. So it looks like that the consumer which was created later takes precedence.

Is it possible to configure kafka such that a consumer which was created earlier takes precedence for reads?

My setup includes 3 brokers and 1 consumer group id. In addition this [property](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/consumer.html) `auto.offset.reset` is set to `earliest` (changin it to `latest` doesn't resolve the issue). I'm using this Go [library](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go) for kafka. This is my setup code:

```golang
import (
    "log"
    "github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-go/kafka"
)

func getConfig() *kafka.ConfigMap {
    return &kafka.ConfigMap{
        "metadata.broker.list": conf.KafkaBrokers,
        "security.protocol":    "SASL_SSL",
        "sasl.mechanisms":      "SCRAM-SHA-256",
        "sasl.username":        conf.KafkaUsername,
        "sasl.password":        conf.KafkaPassword,
        "group.id":             conf.KafkaGroupID,
        "default.topic.config": kafka.ConfigMap{"auto.offset.reset": "earliest"},
        //"debug":                           "generic,broker,security",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within a consumer group, each partition is consumed by a single consumer. When consumers join the group, one of them computes the assignment which consists of the list of partitions each consumer will handle.

In your client, this can be configured via [`partition.assignment.strategy`](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md). This defaults to `range` which follows the implementation of Apache Kafka's [`RangeAssignor`](http://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RangeAssignor.html).

Quoting the Javadoc:

> The range assignor works on a per-topic basis. For each topic, we lay out the available partitions in numeric order and the consumers in lexicographic order. We then divide the number of partitions by the total number of consumers to determine the number of partitions to assign to each consumer. If it does not evenly divide, then the first few consumers will have one extra partition.
>
> For example, suppose there are two consumers C0 and C1, two topics t0 and t1, and each topic has 3 partitions, resulting in partitions t0p0, t0p1, t0p2, t1p0, t1p1, and t1p2.
>
> The assignment will be:
>
> ```
> C0: [t0p0, t0p1, t1p0, t1p1]
> C1: [t0p2, t1p2]
> ```

Consumers are ordered by their member ID which is a generated on the broker side. It is based on the consumer `client.id` and a random UUID.

In practice, I does not matter which consumer gets assigned each partition so I wouldn't focus too much of that part. Instead it's important to understand how partitions are assigned and identify the strategy that works best for your use cases.

For completeness, `confluent-kafka-go` also supports other strategies such as: `roundrobin` and `cooperative-sticky`.